# How to determine whether a threaded rod will rotate under load

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, modeling, mechanical

A part of a structure I am designing incorporates a large threaded rod (1") diameter mounted vertically both for structural strength and for the potential to adjust the height of the top mounted surface. The bottom surface houses the nut for the threaded rod, as well as a handle to adjust the height by rotating the rod.

I want to be able to analyze both how much torque will be needed to rotate the lead screw under load, and whether the high forces in a possible failure condition (30kN) will make the lead screw start rotating on its own.

I tried making a free body diagram for this, to no avail. The more I think about this problem the more it seems impossible.

I know that lead screws and threaded rod nuts are capable of rotating under their own weight, so would increasing the load result in higher chances of rotation or lower? And why?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to approximate metal friction coefficient as 0.2 (better approach might be to solve for the coefficient needed)?  Screw is a wedge wrapped around a pole.

Comment: The pitch angle usually defines the limit of threads that self-run or not, but if you don't want it to move then pins or locknuts are the classic methods.

Comment: As  you go around the circle, (1 thread) the friction cancels its own horizontal component out. You need the torque friction coefficient (i think) and there's no way of knowing that

Comment: I found a formula from Shigleys mechanical design textbook for the torque required to lower/raise a lead screw! That works to figure this out as well, and I have found that for my application the lead screw will never practically rotate on its own. Here is the link for anyone who wants to check it out https://www.meadinfo.org/2009/07/lead-screw-design-calculator-metric-iso.html